# For PayPal 2016 security roadmap, Can we expect a patch from Magento?

Tags: magento-enterprise, paypal-express

**IPN Verification Postback to HTTPS**

Magento is using  https://www.paypal.com as a postback url for IPN, but PayPal’s recommendation is ipnpb.paypal.com (http://screencast.com/t/pbGcUDXw)
As per the goal of this section Magento is already using the https url, but for PayPal’s recommendation can we expect a patch from Magento?

Comment: I believe the better place to ask this question is its issue tracker in github: https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues

Comment: @Zefiryn Magento 2 isn't tagged in this question, so we should assume Magento 1.x

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I sent this to the Magento Security team and their response was:

> We follow recommendations of PayPal and updated URLs in M2 however
>   there are no consequences listed on a PayPal website for using
>   paypal.com endpoint, just a recommendation to change it which means no
>   patch needed for previous versions until farther notice from PayPal

**Update to my answer:**

Meanwhile Magento released a patch for this for Magento 1:

"SUPEE-8167  This patch contains update for Magento with new PayPal IPN server location. It is required to keep PayPal processing transactions past June 30, 2017. - Added May 8, 2017"

See also: https://magento.com/tech-resources/download